# admob revenue decresed, should i upgrade sdk

Tags: cordova, admob

in 2017 December , i received a mail from google saying that

> Beginning Jan 23, 2018, Google Mobile Ads SDK versions older than 7.0.0 for Android and 7.0.0 for iOS will no longer be supported. Publishers with these older versions will not be able to serve ads in their apps(s). Please ensure that you have upgraded to the latest version of the Google Mobile Ads SDK

i have not done anything from my side and the admob was working normally in december, but in this january my admob revenue were decresed 50% of previous month. my app downloads are same as previous months and i suspect something wrong, i dont know how to fix it and where to ask this question. should i upgrade admob sdk, is this the reason of the revenue drop in?

Comment: check your fill rate ( match rate), we have seen similar drop as match rate was less

Comment: match rate +2.88% (+3.11%)